# Filtering multiple conditions from a Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter out data from a dataframe using multiple conditions using multiple columns. I tried doing so like this:

```
arrival_delayed_weather = [[[flight_data_finalcopy["ArrDelay"] > 0]] & [[flight_data_finalcopy["WeatherDelay"]>0]]]
arrival_delayed_weather_filter = arrival_delayed_weather[["UniqueCarrier", "AirlineID"]]
print arrival_delayed_weather_filter
```

However I get this error message:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'

How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need `()` instead `[]`:

```
arrival_delayed_weather = (flight_data_finalcopy["ArrDelay"] > 0) & 
                           (flight_data_finalcopy["WeatherDelay"]>0)
```

But it seems you need [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) for selecting columns `UniqueCarrier` and `AirlineID` by `mask` - a bit modified [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (flight_data_finalcopy["ArrDelay"] > 0) & 
        (flight_data_finalcopy["WeatherDelay"]>0)
arrival_delayed_weather_filter=flight_data_finalcopy.ix[mask, ["UniqueCarrier","AirlineID"]]
```

Sample:

```
flight_data_finalcopy = pd.DataFrame({'ArrDelay':[0,2,3],
                                      'WeatherDelay':[0,0,6],
                                      'UniqueCarrier':['s','a','w'],
                                      'AirlineID':[1515,3546,5456]})

print (flight_data_finalcopy)
   AirlineID  ArrDelay UniqueCarrier  WeatherDelay
0       1515         0             s             0
1       3546         2             a             0
2       5456         3             w             6

mask = (flight_data_finalcopy["ArrDelay"] > 0) & (flight_data_finalcopy["WeatherDelay"]>0)
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool

arrival_delayed_weather_filter=flight_data_finalcopy.ix[mask, ["UniqueCarrier","AirlineID"]]
print (arrival_delayed_weather_filter)
  UniqueCarrier  AirlineID
2             w       5456
```

Comment: Thanks ! , But what if i want to perform math operations like adding two columns of data? is it done the same way? @jezrael

Comment: I am not sure if understand, but maybe need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).  I think the best is create new question - small advice - [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @DeepakM jezrael answered the question you posted.  If you have a different question now, it would be best to ask another quesiton.

Comment: ok, i tried that code exactly the way you have it with  ix it however threw an error: " ValueError: too many values to unpack"  @jezrael

Comment: @DeepakM - sorry, there was typo. Now I add sample to solution, please check it.

Comment: Thanks man ! worked like a charm, .loc i should have thought of that ! @jezrael

Comment: Ya, you can use `ix` or `loc`, there is not problem. But if check [revison 2](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40510840/revisions) you need remove `[]` from `mask`.