# Dataframe filtering with multiple conditions on different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'Item':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 
'A':[142, 11, 50, 60, 12], 
'B':[55, 65, 130, 14, 69],
'C':[68, -18, 65, 16, 17],
'D':[60, 0, 150, 170, 130],
'E':[230, 200, 5, 10, 160]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

representing different items and the corresponding values related to some of their parameters (e.g. length, width, and so on). However, not all the reported values are acceptable, in fact each item has a different range of allowed values:

A and B go from -100 to +100

C goes from -70 to +70

D and E go from +100 to +300

So, as you can see, some items show values outside limits for just one parameter (e.g. item 2 is outside for parameter D), while others are outside for more than one parameter (e.g. item 1 is outside for both parameters A and D).

I need to analyze these data and get a table reporting:
how many items are outside for just one parameter and the name of this parameter
how many items are outside for more than one parameter and the name of those parameter
To be clearer: I need a simple simple way to know how many items are failed and for which parameters. For example: four items out of five are failed, and 2 of them (item #1 and item#3) for two parameters (item #1 for A and D, item #3 for B and E), while items #2 and #4 are out for one parameter (item #2 for D, item #4 for E)

I have tried to define the following masks:

```
df_mask_1 = abs(df['A'])>=100
df_mask_2 = abs(df['B'])>=100
df_mask_3 = abs(df['C'])>=70
df_mask_4 = ((df['D']<=110) | (df['D']>=800))
df_mask_5 = ((df['E']<=110) | (df['E']>=800))
```

to get the filtered dataframe:

```
filtered_df = df[df_mask_1 & df_mask_2 & df_mask_3 & df_mask_4 & df_mask_5]
```

but what I obtain is just an empty dataframe. I have also tried with

```
filtered_df = df.loc[(df_mask_1) & (df_mask_2) & (df_mask_3) & (df_mask_4) & (df_mask_5)]
```

but the result does not change.
Any suggestion?

Comment: It's coming back empty as there are no rows in your dataframe that fit all of your conditions.  For example, the only row that satisfies mask1 is the first row, so everything else will be filtered out by mask 1. Then that remaining row doesn't satisfy mask2 so is removed etc. leaving nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering multiple conditions from a Dataframe in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510820/filtering-multiple-conditions-from-a-dataframe-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but so, how should I change the code (or the conditions) to get the right answer?

Comment: If the final mask i mean `df_mask_1 & df_mask_2 & df_mask_3 & df_mask_4 & df_mask_5` doesn't contains any True the df will be empty. Check if the boolean logic is correct on bool values

Comment: @heartbit it is unclear what result you want to achieve. Could you perhaps add an expected output to your question to help understand what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer by Corralien and taking advantage of what's written by tiitinha, and considering the possibility to have some NaN values, here is how I put it all together:

```
df.replace([np.nan],  np.inf,inplace=True)

condlist = [df['A'].between(-100, 100) | df['A'] == np.inf,
            df['B'].between(-100, 100) | df['B'] == np.inf,
            df['C'].between(-70, 70) | df['C'] == np.inf,
            df['D'].between(100, 300) | df['D'] == np.inf,
            df['E'].between(100, 300) | df['E'] == np.inf]
```

To get the total number of failed parameters for each item:

```
bool_df = ~pd.concat(condlist, axis=1).astype('bool')

df['#Fails'] = bool_df.sum(axis=1)
```

To know who are the parameters out of limits, for each item:

```
df['Fail'] = pd.concat(condlist, axis=1).melt(ignore_index=False) \
               .loc[lambda x: ~x['value']].groupby(level=0)['variable'].apply(list)
```

In this way I get two columns with the wanted results.

Answer (score 2):

Use a condition list then flat your dataframe with `melt` then keep rows where condition is False (`~x`) then unpivot your dataframe with `groupby_apply`:

```
condlist = [df['A'].between(-100, 100),
            df['B'].between(-100, 100),
            df['C'].between(-70, 70),
            df['D'].between(100, 300),
            df['E'].between(100, 300)]

df['Fail'] = pd.concat(condlist, axis=1).melt(ignore_index=False) \
               .loc[lambda x: ~x['value']].groupby(level=0)['variable'].apply(list)


# Output:
  Item    A    B   C    D    E    Fail
0    1  142   55  68   60  230  [A, D]
1    2   11   65 -18    0  200     [D]
2    3   50  130  65  150    5  [B, E]
3    4   60   14  16  170   10     [E]
4    5   12   69  17  130  160     NaN
```

**Note**: if your dataframe is large and you only need to display failed items, use : `df[df['Fail'].notna()]` to filter out your dataframe.

**Note 2**: `variable` and `value` are the default column names when you [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) a dataframe.

Comment: Not exactly (but it can be usefull).

Comment: @heartbit. Explain us how can I reformat this dataframe to be your expected output.

Comment: Not exactly. Consider that the dataframe can be very long and with a lot of values, so it is not feasible to search and count any False statement. I need a simple simple way to know how many items are failed and for which parameters. For example: four items out of five are failed, and 2 of them (item #1 and item#3) for two parameters (item #1 for A and D, item #3 for B and E), while items #2 and #4 are out for one parameter (item #2 for D, item #4 for E)

Comment: Can you check my update please?

Comment: Yeah, it seems the right answer! Can you please explain better the lines of code? What the \ you used before .set_index(df['Item'])? And the line (~out * out.columns).apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i], axis=1)

Comment: I updated again my answer, now I know what you need.

Comment: @heartbit. Are my explanations sufficiently clear?

Comment: Yes, thank you really much! Can I also ask you how to handle the case where there is some NaN? Indeed in this case the code got an error and stops

Answer (score 0):

The result from the example code is what it should be. The code `filtered_df = df[df_mask_1 & df_mask_2 & df_mask_3 & df_mask_4 & df_mask_5]` applies all masks to the data, hence `df_mask_1` and `df_mask_2` alone would result in empty table (as there are no items where A and B are both over 100).

If you are looking to create a table with information on how many items have parameters outside limits, I'd suggest doing according to Corralien's answer and summing per row to get the amount of limits broken.

Taking Corralien's answer, then

```
a = pd.concat([df['A'].between(-100, 100),
           df['B'].between(-100, 100),
           df['C'].between(-70, 70),
           df['D'].between(100, 300),
           df['E'].between(100, 300)], axis=1)

b = a.sum(axis=1)
```

where b gives per item the amount of limits "broken"

```
0    3
1    4
2    3
3    4
4    5
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Anyway, I guess it needs a modification to get the right result in terms of number of broken limits: you have to get a series containing the logical NOT of each value: temp = ~a.astype('bool'). After that, you can finally find  
b = temp.sum(axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the [pandas.DataFrame.agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) function like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Defining a limit checker function
def limit_check(values, limit):
    return (abs(values) >= limit).sum()

# Applying different limits checks to columns
res = df.agg({
    'A': lambda x: limit_check(x, 100),
    'B': lambda x: limit_check(x, 100),
    'C': lambda x: limit_check(x, 70),
    'D': lambda x: limit_check(x, 800),
    'E': lambda x: limit_check(x, 800),
})
print(res)
```

For the sample data you provided it will result in

```py
A    1
B    1
C    0
D    0
E    0
dtype: int64
```